# ruby on rails: instance variable returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been trying to push the input data from my form to the database using the create function, but the instance variable in create function keeps returning '*nil*' and after the '*begin transaction*', it does '*rollback transaction*'

The model function works fine as I get the desired parsed data, and so does the *timetables_params* function. But *timetables_params[:start_time]* always returns *'nil'* even though the *timetables_params* returns all the *start_time* values and *end_time* values.

How can I fix this?

Here is my **controller**

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @timetables = @user.timetable.all
end

def new
  @timetable = Timetable.new
end

def create
 timetables_params[:start_time] = Timetable.parse_timetable_time(timetables_params, 'start')
 timetables_params[:end_time] = Timetable.parse_timetable_time(timetables_params, 'end')
 @timetable = Timetable.create(timetables_params)
 if @timetable.save
   flash[:success] = "Done"
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end

private
  def timetables_params
     params.require(:timetable).permit(:user_id, :start_time, :end_time)
  end
end
```

Here is my **model**

```
belongs_to :user
attr_accessor :user, :start_time, :end_time

def self.parse_timetable_time(hash, type)
   date_string = hash["#{type}_time(1i)"].to_s + "=" + hash["#{type}_time(2i)"].to_s + "=" + hash["#{type}_time(3i)"]
   Time.parse(date_string)
end
```

Comment: Why is the transaction rolling back? What else does the console output/log include?

Comment: It just includes:
<ActionController::Parameters {"start_time(1i)"=>"", "start_time(2)"=>"1", "start_time(3i)"=>"1", "start_time(4i)"=>"00", .....} permitted: true>
begin transaction
rollback transaction
Rendering timetable/new.html.erb within layouts/application

Comment: Change the `create` in `@timetable = Timetable.create(timetables_params)` to `create!` and the `save` underneath it to `save!` and re-run it. Then look at the console to see if there are any exceptions thrown.

Comment: you have a typo in `(hash.type)` should be comma

Comment: changing the create and save returns an error that the user must exist, but it is solved by current_user.timetables.build(timetables_params). However, that still returns 'nil' values except for user_id.

Comment: you can't assign/modify values of params through `timetables_params`, you need to use `params[:timetable][:start_time]=`. Btw, in Rails you don't need to parse time params (1i, 2i,...) Rails does it auto

Comment: Rails still returns nil values except for user_id, even if I don't parse time params.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not set the `user` since its `belongs_to :user` and i dont see it anywhere in your code. That's why its rolling back and you probably required `user_id` in your Timetable model. My suggestion is below

**Instead of:**

```
@timetable = Timetable.create(timetables_params)
```

**Use build:**

```
@timetable = current_user.timetables.build(timetables_params)
```

Comment: Atleast that returns @timetable with a user_id but all the other values such as id, start_time and end_time are still nil. I don't understand why timetables_params[:start_time] = Timetable.parse_timetable_time(timetables_params, 'start') isn't assigning the value

Comment: Its not advisable to alter the params. use @timetable.start_time = ... Use byebug and make sure that your function parse_timetable_time is working as expected.

Comment: My parse_timetable_time works perfectly, however using _@timetable.start_time_ doesn't work because _@timetable_ still returns 'nil' values for everything except user_id (even with the use of _@timetable = current_user.timetables.build(timetables_params)_.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help above, but turns out that I just had to add the following lines in the model and modify the controller create function:

**model**

```
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :start_time, :end_time, presence: true
```

**controller**

```
def create 
  @timetable = current_user.timetables.build(timetables_params)
  if @timetable.save
    flash[:success] = "Done"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
```

And, I don't necessarily need to parse the datetime values, Rails does do it automatically